# How to get current selected tab index after page reload, i am using Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels?

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, html

I  have two tabs here,

```
 <ul class="TabbedPanelsTabGroup">
          <li class="TabbedPanelsTab" id="tFirst">Basic Information</li>
          <li class="TabbedPanelsTab" id="tSecond">Company Information</li>
        </ul>

.....
...

 var TabbedPanels1 = new Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels("TabbedPanels1",{ defaultTab:0 });
```

after page reload how can i get currently active tab index .
can you help me,thanks in advance...

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: Here two tabs are sharing same page information, and gets entire page reload after saving information. After page reload first tab getting active which is default one.

Comment: pass this in parameter and then get the current tab in parameter

Comment: can you give some piece of code that what you are saying ,i am new to apex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In controller::
var declaration:

```
 public integer currenttabindex{get;set;}
```

code in specific method in which it is gettng reload::

```
IF(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('currindex') != '') {
            currenttabindex=integer.valueOf(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('currindex'));
            if(currenttabindex!=0 && currenttabindex!=null){
                PageReference profPage= new PageReference('/BLN_Profile_HelperPage?id='+currenttabindex);
                profPage.setRedirect(true);
                return profPage;
            }else{

                    currenttabindex= 0;
                    PageReference profPage= new PageReference('/BLN_Profile_HelperPage?id='+currenttabindex);
                    profPage.setRedirect(true);
                    return profPage;
            }
        }
```

---

In page::

calling action funtioin:

```
<apex:commandButton value="Save"    styleClass="button-a blue"  onclick="currTabIndex();" >    
    </apex:commandButton>

<apex:actionFunction name="currenttabindexp" reRender="garbage6" action="{!updatedetails}" status="AjaxLoader" >
           <apex:param name="currindex" value="" assignTo="{!currenttabindex}" />
    </apex:actionFunction>
```

javascript code::

```
function currTabIndex() {

       var curIndex = TabbedPanels1.getCurrentTabIndex();

       if (curIndex == 0) {

           currenttabindexp(curIndex);
       } else {

           currenttabindexp(curIndex);
       }
   }

   var urlpage = window.location.href;
   var n = urlpage.search("1");

   if (n != -1) {

       var TabbedPanels1 = new Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels("TabbedPanels1", {defaultTab: 1  });
   } else {
       var TabbedPanels1 = new Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels("TabbedPanels1", {defaultTab: 0  });
   }
```